# ACF select/dropdown field values based on other true/false fields

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, dropdown, advanced-custom-fields

I struggle a bit in creating a piece of code, that will have an impact on Advanced Custom Fields within my wordpress instance.

**What is the way it should work?**

On the admin dashboard/backend, while creating a post a user has access to two tabs (genereated through ACF). In the first tab, there are three toggle buttons (true / false) called: fruits_selection, veggies_selection and items_selection. In the second tab there is a dropdown/select field called platform. I want to avoid providing 'fixed' list of values. Instead I wanted to leave it up to a user. So when he/she marks specific button, then on the select field those values should be visible.

So IF a user will set fruits_selection to TRUE, then the dropdown should have available values [value : label]:

- apple-bundles : Mix of apples,
- banana-bundles : Bananas basket,
- kiwi-set : Tasty kiwi set,

IF a user will set veggies_selection to TRUE, then the dropdown should have available value: potato-bag : 10lbs Potato Bag

IF a user will set items_selection to TRUE, then the dropdown should have available value: basket : Wooden basket

Obviously, the more buttons are set to true, the more values will be available in the select field.

This is my current code:

```
function acf_load_platform_field_choices( $field ) {
    
    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();
    $choices = array();
    
    $fruits = get_field('fruits_selection');
    $veggies = get_field('veggies_selection');
    $items = get_field('items_selection');
    
    if( $fruits ) {
        $choices = array_push('apple-bundles : Mix of apples', 'banana-bundles : Bananas basket', 'kiwi-set : Tasty kiwi set');
    }

    if( $veggies ) {
        $choices = array_push('potato-bag : 10lbs Potato Bag');
    }

    if( $items ) {
        $choices = array_push('basket : Wooden basket');
    }
  
    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {
        
        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {
            
            $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    // return the field
    return $field;
    
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=platform', 'acf_load_platform_field_choices');
```

Unfortunately, my current code doesn't work. It always makes the dropdown blank (no values) no matter of the button (true/false) selection. On top of that while trying to save it i get the info **Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.**

So what im doing here wrong?

Comment: Not sure that you are on the right path here - Your `get_field()` functions only works on an existing posts object - So if you are doing this in new posts, then it hasn't been saved yet, and if you are doing this on existing posts, then the change would only happen on update.  I would look to javascript for this task.

Comment: @Stender I've tried to create sth you said in pure javascript - take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/0jL8kd1f/ but somehow the function doesn't execute :(

Comment: sure - Here - https://jsfiddle.net/r42c8xja/ - You didn't call the function on anything. And you hadn't implemented a reset function on the select, so it would always append.